# Convert bytes to string in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding, byte

I am trying to read and process a file. This wroks perfectly fine in Python2.7 but I can't get it working in Python 3.
In Python 2.7 it works without providing any encoding whereas in Python 3 I have tried all combinations with and without encoding.

After deep diving, I found that the way content returned by `read` is different in both the versions.

Code in Python 2.7 that works:

```
>>> f = open('resource.cgn', 'r')
>>> content = f.read()
>>> type(content)
<type 'str'>
>>> content[0:20]
'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03\xa3,ess to'
>>> content[0]
'\x04'
```

However in Python 3:

```
>>> f = open('resource.cgn','r')
>>> content = f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xa0 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> f = open('resource.cgn','rb')
>>> content = f.read()
>>> type(content)                   
<class 'bytes'>
>>> content[0:20]
b'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03\xa3,ess to'
>>> content[0]
4
>>> content.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 10: 
invalid start byte
```

I would like to get the same output as in Python 2.7. The `content` should be of type `string` and `content[0]` should be str `'\x04'` and not int `4`

Any pointers on how can I get this? I have tried encodings without any success.

Comment: Have you tried `content.decode('unicode_escape')`?

Comment: How about `content[:1]`? That'll give you `b'\x04'`.

Comment: Solution of @SamChats works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.X's `str` is now 2.X's `unicode` by default and file objects opened in text mode in 3.X attempt to decode and encode when your files are read from or written to, respectively. `str` of 2.X is now `bytes` in 3.X. There's really very minor differences between 3.X `bytes` and 2.X's `str` both essentially hold 8-bit text.

Here's a simple trick to convert `` b'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03\xa3,ess to' `` to `str` in 3.X:

```
>>> content = ''.join(chr(x) for x in b'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03\xa3,ess to')
>>> content
'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03£,ess to'
>>> content[0]
'\x04
```

Decoding the `bytes` string fails because you have invalid UTF-8 character bytes, same for ASCII.

However, it's wise to mention that `bytes` is meant to process binary data and `str` is for Unicode strings only in 3.X. It's recommended then to use `bytes` instead of `str` for binary strings in 3.X:

```
>>> content = b'\x04#lwq \x7f`g \xa0\x03\xa3,ess to'
>>> hex(content[0])
'0x4'
```

Comment: This works. Is there a way I can convert it back from `str` to bytes without providing an encoding?

Comment: @HusainBasrawala To convert from `str` to `bytes`  without providing encoding: `bytes(ord(x) for x in content)` and that's pretty much it :-)

Comment: @HusainBasrawala: no, you can't convert `unicode` to `bytes` without using  some `encoding` (the code in the previous comment is just trying to invent its own scheme something similar to `.encode('latin1')`). If you want to convert from bytes to unicode or from unicode to bytes you need to provide an encoding: [There Ain’t No Such Thing As Plain Text.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for pointing that out. `ord` returns only the Unicode character code point without encoding.

Comment: @direprobs: Don't misled  people. Again, **you cannot convert unicode to bytes without using some encoding** Again, your code tries to reinvent the wheel. Compare `'abc\xf7'.encode('latin1')` with the output from  your code. [They are the same](http://ideone.com/bLHXtf).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've not "mislead" anyone for anything. I've not stated in that comment that this is an 'encoding scheme'; "you cannot convert unicode to bytes without using some encoding" but what is encoding?"_ _"The rules for translating a Unicode string into a sequence of bytes are called an encoding."_ OP wanted to attain the behavior of `str` in 2.X, in `str` of 3.X using. I've stated *explicitly in my answer this is *not* the way to go. OP obviously deals with binary data. _"Don't misled people."_ It should be "don't mislead people." :-)